# Is there any function in JS like this int.to_bytes() in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have found somewhere on Stack Overflow that we can achieve `int.from_bytes()`   functionality in Node.js by using:

```
const buf = Buffer.from([0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]) // 0x12345678 = 305419896
console.log(buf.readUInt32BE(0)) // 305419896
```

Is there any alternative available for  `int.to_bytes()`? I want to first use `int.from_bytes()` and then need to do some manipulations and again want to reconvert it using `int.to_bytes()`.

Comment: Hi, just use `writeUInt32BE` instead of `read`...

Comment: i am getting different results   ... this is the  python logic which i want to implement                       i = int.from_bytes(full, 'big') << (2 * (bs % 4)) # left shift in pad bits return (i.to_bytes(bfs, 'big'))but when it is converting using to_bytes it is also utilizing "bfs" and taking i is calculated using from_bytes

Answer (score 0):

You can get back the original bytes using the `.values()` method which return an Array Iterator, so it can be used with the spread operator or `Array.from` if you need:

```js
const buf = Buffer.from([0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]) // 0x12345678 = 305419896
console.log(buf.readUInt32BE(0)) // 305419896

console.log(...buf)
// 18 52 86 120

const arr = Array.from(buf)
console.log(arr)
// [18, 52, 86, 120]
```

Note that `console.log` output is in decimal, not hexadecimal.

Comment: i = int.from_bytes(full, 'big') << (2 * (bs % 4))  # left shift in pad bits
        return (i.to_bytes(bfs, 'big'))       This is the logic i want to implement but when it is converting using to_bytes it is also utilizing "bfs"  and taking i  is calculated using from_bytes

Answer (score -2):

in python, class `int` has a classmethod `from_bytes`

```py
bytes = [0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]
a = int.from_bytes(bytes, "big", signed=False)
print(a)
#305419896
```

Comment: but i want to achieve the same functionality in nodejs